# Уведомление администрации, конкретно после нажатия инлайн кнопки с URL ссылкой. [config / callback_data / InlineKeyboardButton]

Tags: python, telegram-bot, callback, config, inline

#### Вот так скажем чистый пример, когда уведомление админу, приходит вместе с основным сообщением.
  Но очень хочется, чтобы уведомление приходило, конкретно после того, как юзер нажмет на кнопку с URL ссылкой.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='klik')
async def send_message(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    pro = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1,
                                inline_keyboard=[
                                    [
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', url='URL')
                                    ]])

    user_id = call.from_user.id
    user_name = call.from_user.username
    user = await commands.select_user(user_id)
    count_refs = await commands.count_refs(user_id)
    await call.message.answer('ТЕКСТ', reply_markup=pro)

    await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=config.admins[0], text=f'ТЕКСТ\n'
                                                             f'@{user_name}\n'
                                                             f'<code>{user_id}</code>\n'
                                                             f'{user.server}\n'
                                                             f'{user.status}\n'
                                                             f'{count_refs}')
```

#### Вот пример, как я безуспешно пытался реализовать задуманное

```
        @dp.callback_query_handler(text='klik')
async def send_message(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    pro = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1,
                                inline_keyboard=[
                                    [
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='go_to_lk', url='URL')
                                    ]])

    user_id = call.from_user.id
    user_name = call.from_user.username
    user = await commands.select_user(user_id)
    count_refs = await commands.count_refs(user_id)
    await call.message.answer('ТЕКСТ', reply_markup=pro)

    await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=config.admins[0], text=f'ТЕКСТ\n'
                                                             f'@{user_name}\n'
                                                             f'<code>{user_id}</code>\n'
                                                             f'{user.server}\n'
                                                             f'{user.status}\n'
                                                             f'{count_refs}')

    #Либо так
    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'go_to_lk')
    ################################################################
    
    @dp.callback_query_handler(text='go_to_lk')
async def sen_message(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer('KYKYKY')
    await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=config.admins[0], text='DAROVAAAAAA')

#Если убрать URL и оставить callback_data, эти меседжи успешно дойдут
```

#### Просто напросто, URL как будто перебивает калбек, или оно так и не должно работать.
Еще пробовал добавлять туда состояния, тоже безуспешно.
Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь поможет с данным вопросиком :3